# How to get Python to stop at a certain number while showing "iterations"

Tags: python

My assignment is to write a Python script that uses `random` to generate a random number inside a loop, and that loop keeps running until it generates a 4.00 gpa. I was able to see a demo of what the final assignment is suppose to look like.

Right now I am stuck with

```
while True:
   x = random.uniform(1,4)
   print(x)
   if x ==(4):
       break
```

When I run my code, it looks nothing like the demo the professor shows
[image]

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of `count` ? like `count = count + 1` inside the while loop, with `count` initialized to `0` before the start of the loop

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current and expected output!

Comment: `random.uniform(1,4)` returns a high-precision float. The chance it will be exactly "4" (or any other precise number) is 0 by definition. Round it to 1 or 2 digits for the loop to ever stop.

Comment: As @Aryerez pointed out, you may want to rewrite `x = random.uniform(1,4)` to `x = random.randint(1,4)`

Comment: @Aryerez There are only finitely many floating point numbers in the range, so individual values do have non-zero probabilities; it's not like a uniform distribution on a range of real numbers. However, according to the docs, *"The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding"* https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform so it's probably impossible due to being the upper bound of the interval, rather than any other reason.

Comment: @kaya3 Do you want to run a test, run it with `if x == *any single value inside the range you choose in advance*`, and let me know when it stopped? In reality there infinite floating numbers between **any** two numbers. Because of the maximun precision limitation used by `python`, it becomes finite, but it still not what you would like to do with your computer in the years to come, and surely not the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: I estimate that your experiment would take on the order of hundreds or thousands of years. But you are using a definition of "reality" that I am not familiar with; in reality, there are finitely many floating point numbers, because 2^64 is a finite number. The maximum precision limitation used in Python is simply the IEEE 754 definition of a floating point number; there are not infinitely many floating point numbers in other languages, either.

Comment: By the way, if you let me choose the range myself, I can choose `a = 2**52` and `b = 2**52 + 2`. My loop `while random.uniform(a, b) != a: c += 1` increased the counter to 3 and then terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
import random
iteration_count = 0
while True:
    iteration_count += 1
    x = round(random.uniform(1,4), 2)
    print(x)
    if x == 4:
        print('Iteration count: %i' % iteration_count )
        break
```

Your Code is very unlikely to ever end since you are generating `floats` which are unlikely to be exactly 4. So you should round the values like your prof did.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

i = 0
while True:
   x = random.uniform(1,4)
   print(i)
   i+=1
   print(x)
   if x == (4):
       break
```

where `i` - is counter of iterations

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to two decimals with `ro

```
iterations = 0
while True:
    iterations += 1
    x = round(random.uniform(1, 4), 2)
    print(x)
    if x == 4.0:
        break

print(f'Iterations: {iterations}')
```

Comment: What's the purpose of converting to a string and then back to float?